# SQL Subquery: Column not found

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT  t1.`userID`,`name`, COUNT( * ) AS  `count`, (SELECT `val` FROM `user-data` WHERE `userID` = t1.userID AND `keyID` = 2 LIMIT 1) AS `staff`
FROM  `activity` t1
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = t1.`userID`
WHERE 
t1.`userID` <> 0
GROUP BY t1.`userID` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Which works, it takes about 2 seconds.  But I want to find entries where `staff <> 1`:

```
SELECT  t1.`userID`,`name`, COUNT( * ) AS  `count`, (SELECT `val` FROM `user-data` WHERE `userID` = t1.userID AND `keyID` = 2 LIMIT 1) AS `staff`
FROM  `activity` t1
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = t1.`userID`
WHERE 
t1.`userID` <> 0
AND `staff` <> 1
GROUP BY t1.`userID` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC LIMIT 10
```

I get the error:  `Unknown column 'staff' in 'where clause'`

I can put the subquery in the WHERE clause, but then the query takes 70 seconds.

But surely I should be able to access the column i've reference in the SELECT statement?

Comment: `AND staff` < ` is incomplete

Comment: Just checking, did you forgot to add AND `staff` <> 1 in your query?

Comment: Nope, you should not. The select list is processed **after** the `where` clause.

Comment: @lloiacono Yes sorry I typed too fast!

Comment: Can the subquery return more than 1 rows if you remove the limit clause from it? If no, then you could move the subquery into a join.

Comment: show us table structure

Comment: @Shadow is there a way to reference it then?  Why is putting the subquery in the WHERE clause increasing the time by 70 seconds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the select list is processed after the `where` clause, you cannot reference any calculated field in the `where` clause via its alias.

You can move the subquery into a join, provided it returns a single record only even if there is no limit clause:

```
SELECT  t1.`userID`,`name`, COUNT( * ) AS  `count`, `user-data`.`val` as staff  
FROM  `activity` t1
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = t1.`userID`
LEFT JOIN `user-data` ON `user-data`.`userID`=t1.userID AND `user-data`.`keyID` = 2
WHERE 
    t1.`userID` <> 0
    AND `user-data`.`val` <> 1
GROUP BY t1.`userID`, `user-data`.`val` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @Strawberry: I know where the value of staff comes from, it is described in the subquery. From the subquery you can also derive how the tables are joined together without a schema. If undermining your comment deserves a downvote, then so be it.